# Can I alter just the dual-wielding controls?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In a comment on [Is it possible to use a shield in one hand and magic in the other?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34938/is-it-possible-to-use-a-shield-in-one-hand-and-magic-in-the-other/34940#34940), switching the controls for left arm to left mouse button (and right arm to right mouse button) was mentioned.  I think this makes the dual-wielding system much more intuitive - however, I desperately don't want to have to left click to block and right click to attack (or right click to shoot my bow, left click to melee with it, etc).

I didn't see anything in the settings to alter mappings for dual wielding only - is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you on PC or console? I'd be surprised if there wasn't a mod to fix this by now, but if you're not on a PC I won't bother looking for one.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie PC - if there is a mod to do this, I'd love to know what it is.

Comment: Surprisingly I haven't found one. I *have* found [a mod that lets you parry while dual-wielding](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=11006) though, which has the side-effect of making left-click be alway attack, since right-click becomes parry. Editing that mod might give a clue to how to write the desired mod, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you play with a controller it is mapped correctly (right trigger controls right hand). There is no way to just map dual wielding on the PC

Answer (score -2):

You could put your shield in your right hand and the sword in the left.

Comment: This is only a solution if I do not swap the mouse click (M1 for primary, M2 for secondary) and if I use sword and shield, which is not dual wielding at all.

Comment: @Ian I misunderstood your question then. So you want to left click to swing a 2-handed weapon, fire a bow, swing a 1-handed weapon with a shield, and swing the left weapon while dual wielding?

Comment: Bingo.  I want to keep original key mappings when not dual-wielding, and have each hand controlled by each side when dual-wielding (either a weapon or magic).

Comment: You can'r equip a shield in your right hand.